# Inequality proof, power function, 'sum of the power and power of the sum'

Tags: inequality

I got a question regarding the following two relations:

$$0<c<b<a, 0<\alpha<1,$$

$$(1-\alpha)\log\frac{3}{2}\text{ and  }\log(a^\alpha+b^\alpha+c^\alpha)-\alpha \log(a+b+c)-\left[\log(a^\alpha+b^\alpha)-\alpha\log(a+b)\right]$$

I checked a few numbers, and made the figure using Mathematica, which shows the former is larger than the second one.

I wonder if you guys have ideas on how to prove it analytically.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:proof-writing]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  Sorry. I was gonna choose 'proof', but somehow 'proof writing' auto pops up. Thanks for pointing it out. Just changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality doesn't hold. Take $\alpha = 1/2, a = 1, b=.75, c=.749$.

$LHS=0.202732554, RHS = 0.202892973 > LHS$.

On the other hand if $a=1, b=.9, c=.8$ then $LHS > RHS$ so the other direction doesn't hold either.

BTW: if you fix $a$ and $b$ you can prove the derivative of RHS w.r.t. $c$ is positive, so $RHS$ takes its maximum when $c=b$. After you replace $c$ with $b$ in RHS however, RHS as a function of $b$ is not monotone (if $a=b=c$ you have equality).